# XQuery: declare a function returning nothing

Tags: xquery, basex

```
declare variable $testseq as item()* := ();

declare function local:insertseq($target as item()*, $position as xs:integer?, $inserts as item()*)
as item()* (:might be great if we have a keyword to represent nothing:)
{
  fn:insert-before($target, 1, $inserts) (:change the global sequence:)
  () (:simulate returning nothing, empty sequence:)
};

element test
{
  attribute haha {"&amp;"},
  local:insertseq($testseq, 1, ('a', 'b')),
  $testseq
}
```

I need to collect something into a global sequence while the script running. At the end of the script I release the sequence. The function `insertseq` must return nothing. It is possible with XQuery? Or are there other tricks to do it?

Error from BaseX:

```
$ basex test.xqy
Stopped at /Users/jack/Documents/SHK/XSD2OWL/Workspace/xqy/test.xqy, 7/4:
[XPTY0004] Item expected, sequence found: ("a", "b").
```

Comment: XQuery is a functional language. Even your use of `insert-before` is incorrect: it doesn't modify anything, it returns a new sequence. You need to rethink what you're doing in terms of input/output; if you need a sequence at the end of your processing, then that sequence will need to be part of a return value.

Comment: Some implementations have a "scripting" extension where you have mutable variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer on the title of your original question would actually be:

```
declare function local:f() as empty-sequence() {
  ()
};
```

As you probably want to solve a specific problem, you could think about creating a new question with another title and a corresponding problem description (including a tiny example with the expected input and output).

In functional languages, such as XQuery, variables cannot be reassigned once they have been defined (see [Referential Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)). As a consequence, you’ll need to use recursive functions to repeatedly add values to a sequence. [fn:fold-left](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Higher-Order_Functions#fn:fold-left) can be used as well: it feels challenging when being used for the first time, but once you understand what it does, you don’t want to miss is.